# C: Output difference between printf and vfprintf when using the exact same inputs

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a logger function that logs stuff to a file in a printf manner but, if enabled, it will also log to the console. I'm trying it out with a custom function that uses a custom string struct representing a number and transforms it into an actual number.

The main function:

```
#define MSG "0xab45cdef"
int main(){

   String s;
   stringInit(&s);
   stringSetString(&s,MSG,sizeof(MSG));
   stringPrint(&s);
   logOut("\nTransforming to value\n");
   int64_t v = parseValue(s);
   logOut("\n");
   logOut("\nResult %li \n", v);
}
```

My output log function

```
void logOut(const char *control_string, ...){
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen(LOG_OUTPUT,"ab+");

   va_list argptr;
   va_start(argptr,control_string);
   vfprintf(fp,control_string,argptr);
#ifdef LOG_CONSOLE
   printf(control_string,argptr);
#endif
   va_end(argptr);
   fclose(fp);
}
```

My String related functions

```
typedef struct {
   char *s;
   unsigned int  size; 
} String;

void stringInit(String *s){
   s->s = NULL;
   s->size = 0;
}

void stringAddChar(String *s, char c){
   if (s->size > 0){
      // Adding one more char. 
      s->s = (char *) realloc (s->s, (s->size + 1)*sizeof(char));       
   }
   else{
     // First char.
     s->s = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
   }
   s->size++;      
   s->s[s->size-1] = c;
}


void stringFree(String *s){
   if (s->size == 0) return;
   free(s->s);
   s->s = NULL;
   s->size = 0;
}

void stringSetString(String *s, char *str, uint32_t nsize){
   // Clearing the previous string. 
   stringFree(s);
   for (uint32_t i = 0;  i < nsize; i++){
      // This avoids the extra char in a null terminated string. 
      if ((i == nsize-1) && (str[i] == 0)) break;
      stringAddChar(s,str[i]);
   }
}

void stringPrint(String *s){
   for (uint32_t i = 0;  i < s->size; i++){
      logOut("%c",s->s[i]);
   }
}
```

And finally the parseValue function

```
int64_t power(int64_t base, int64_t exp){
   int64_t ans = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < exp; i++){
      ans = ans * base;
   }
   return ans;
}

int64_t parseValue(String input){

   int64_t  base = 10;
   int64_t  res = 0;
   int64_t  maxpow = input.size-1;
   uint32_t start = 0;

   if (input.size > 0){
      // Must check if it is hex or not.       
      if (input.s[0] == '0' && input.s[1] == 'x'){
         base = 16;
         start = 2;
         maxpow = input.size-3;
      }
   }


   for (int i = start; i < input.size; i++){

      int64_t p = maxpow;
      maxpow--;


      char c = toupper(input.s[i]);  

      // printf("Char %d is %d\n",i,c);

      int64_t v = c - 48;

      if ((v >= 0) && (v <= 9)){
         res = res + v*power(base,p);
      }
      else if ((c >= 65) && (c <= 70)){
         if (base == 16){
            v = c - 55;
            res = res + v*power(base,p);
         }
         else{
            logOut("Invalid char %c in a decimal number\n",c);
            return -1;
         }
      }
      else{
         logOut("Invalid digit %d\n",c);
         return -1;       
      }
   }

   return res;
}
```

Now when I run the main the console outputs:

```
pppppppppp
Transforming to value


Result 140726926743712
```

While my log.txt file has this

```
0xab45cdef
Transforming to value


Result 2873478639
```

The content of the log.txt file is correct. So why is the console output different?

Comment: You cannot use a va_list twice. Use va_copy instead.

Comment: @wildplasser va_end then va_start again is another option

Comment: @M.M ... or printing into a string buffer and outputting that twice...

Comment: `printf(control_string,argptr);` is wrong. You can't "print" `va_list` type.

Comment: @M.M I've added the stringFree function. I've tried to use va_end and then va_start again, but either I didn't totally understand you or I didn't work. I'look into va_copy. But I really like the idea of printing to a string buffer and then outputting that. How would that work

Comment: @KamilCuk Then how can I output the control string to the console with all it's parameters?

Comment: I believe you meant to use `vprintf` there of course.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks!!!! This worked!! I also used va_start and va_end with another list. I would gladly put the answer up, but it is your answer. If you put it up I'l mark it as correct

Comment: I'd suggest opening the file as `ab` rather than `ab+` if you're not reading it (which generally you shouldn't be for a log file)

Comment: I'm not! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, your `logOut` function has some mistakes. You can't "re-use" `va_list` after it has been used in another function. The function could look like this:

```
void logOut(const char *control_string, ...){
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen(LOG_OUTPUT,"ab+");
   if (fp == NULL) {
       abort();
   }

   va_list argptr;
   va_start(argptr, control_string);
   if (vfprintf(fp, control_string, argptr) < 0) {
      // handle error
   }
   va_end(argptr);

   fclose(fp);

#ifdef LOG_CONSOLE
   va_start(argptr, control_string); // do not re-use va_list
   vprintf(control_string, argptr);    
// ^ you pass va_list
   va_end(argptr);
#endif
}
```

Notes:

- `realloc(NULL, ...)` is equal to `malloc(...)`. So there is no need to `if (s->size > 0){` inside `stringAddChar` - just call `realloc(s->s`, and make sure that `s->s` is `NULL` when size is zero.
- Your code misses a lot of error handling. A proper way to handle `realloc` is to use a temporary pointer so that original memory will not leak: `void *p = realloc(s->s, ...); if (p == NULL) { free(s->s); /* handle errors */ abort(); } s->s = p;`.
- Try not to use magic numbers in code. `c - 48;` is better written as `c - '0';`.

Comment: Thank you! Both for your answers and your comments in my code. I'm a newbie at C as I usually always use C++. Regards!